# Change sum based on product (select), quantity (text input)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the sum depending on product and qnty selections...

I have this...

```css
input,select{outline:none}
.products{width:200px;border:1px solid;}
.qnty{width:50px;border:1px solid;}
.sum{width:10px;border:0;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<select class="products">
<option value="" select="select">Select Product You Want</option>
<option value="20000">Russian Matryoshka Small (20000 RUB)</option>
<option value="50000">Russian Matryoshka Medium (50000 RUB)</option>
<option value="100000">Russian Matryoshka Large (100000 RUB)</option>
</select> × <input type="text" placeholder="Qnty" class="qnty" /> = <input type="text" class="sum" id="sum" value="0" /> RUB.
```

Where do I put product price to?

By default there SELECT says choose a product. So, when I choose a product there should appear exact same line for next selection. I want to do it myself.. I don't know how... Can you please help me, please? I tried a lot, but it doesn't help...

Thanks.

Comment: I think you will need a price value for each option, otherwise your quantity will not have price to multiply with `sum += price * quantity;`.

Comment: Thank you. I have to put values for each option, yes? But I also then want to send product name with PHP, how will I get its name then?

Comment: can you let us know if our answers, answers your questions regarding getting the total amount. As for the PHP part, you'll probably have to make another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
total = function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var optVal = $('#ddlViewBy option:selected').val();
  var optName = $('#ddlViewBy option:selected').text();
  var quantity = $('#qnty').val();
  sum += optVal * quantity;
  
  $('.total').html(sum);
  
  console.log(optName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="products" id="ddlViewBy">
      <option value="" select="select">Select Product You Want</option>
      <option value="2">Russian Matryoshka Small (2 RUB)</option>
      <option value="5">Russian Matryoshka Medium (5 RUB)</option>
      <option value="10">Russian Matryoshka Large (10 RUB)</option>
    </select>
 ×     <input type="text" placeholder="Qnty" class="qnty" id="qnty" />
 =     <span class="total"></span> RUB.
  
      <button onclick="total()">Total</button>
```

As a follow up answer to my comment regarding summing up the item * quantity you put in the `input`

```
total = function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var optVal = $('#ddlViewBy option:selected').val();
  var quantity = $('#qnty').val();
  sum += optVal * quantity;

  $('.total').html(sum);

  console.log(sum);
}
```

to get the option name you can simply say `.text()` rather than `.val()`

```
var optName = $('#ddlViewBy option:selected').text();
```

Plnkr Example--
https://plnkr.co/edit/xVubsk08LNfYM8by1shV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly name (identify) your widgets to access them later on.

See below code as an example:

```js
var prod = document.getElementById("product"),
     qty = document.getElementById("qty"),
     sum = document.getElementById("sum");

var calculateSum = function() {
  if (prod.value && qty.value)
    sum.value = prod.value * qty.value;
  else
    sum.value = 0;
}

prod.addEventListener("change", calculateSum);
qty.addEventListener("input", calculateSum);
```

```css
input,
select {
  outline: none
}

.products {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.qnty {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.sum {
  width: 50px;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<select id="product" class="products">
<option value="" select="select">Select Product You Want</option>
<option value="20000">Russian Matryoshka Small (20000 RUB)</option>
<option value="50000">Russian Matryoshka Medium (50000 RUB)</option>
<option value="100000">Russian Matryoshka Large (100000 RUB)</option>
</select> × <input type="text" id='qty' placeholder="Qnty" class="qnty" /> = <input type="text" class="sum" id="sum" value="0" /> RUB.
```

Comment: Your answer is great! I like it! :) Thank you!